# How to discover the selected item in TvLazyColumn

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I would like to animate the title of a row in a TVLazyColumn depending on whether it is the one in focus or not.

I can't find how to get which item in the column has the focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `onFocusChanged` modifier to know if an item is in focus or not. Attach the modifier to all rows, and you can make use of `it.hasFocus` to check if the focus is within the respective lazy row.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun App() {
    TvLazyColumn {
        item { AppRow() }
        item { AppRow() }
        item { AppRow() }
        // ...
    }
}

@Composable
fun AppRow() {
    var doesRowHaveFocus by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    TvLazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier
                .onFocusChange {
                    doesRowHaveFocus = it.hasFocus
                }
    ) {
        item { FocusableItem() }
        item { FocusableItem() }
        item { FocusableItem() }
        // ...
    }
}
```